# Next and prev ID on database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a web site, and in admin area I can see users.
I want to add a next and prev link buttons, to quickly change page, but issue is often I delete inactive users, so I have "hole" (i.e.: missing user_id) in my database.

How to show next and prev link?

Table name is "**users**"

ID is named "**user_id**"

I have a function that already show current user id:

```
<?= $user_id; ?>
```

So, actually I do next and prev links as:

```
<?= $user_id-1; ?>
```

and

```
<?= $user_id+1; ?>
```

but, of course, this don't consider missing user_id numbers in my database..

How to do it?

Please consider I'm not a developer, so I need (if you can) a complete instruction I can use.

Thanks in advance

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, if you try some code and find issues then people will help you fix it.  Just a suggestion, but you can use SQL to find the highest Id which is less than (or greater than) the id you currently have.

Comment: If you'll select the 1st row from the rows with user_id less that current one sorted by user_id descending, you'll get previous value. If do backward - you'll get next value.